# Editing an existing report and now a repeating table is out of order

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am editing an existing report.  After adding 2 columns to the end of one of the tables it has a weird behavior that I don't know how to fix or why it starting doing it.  Google searches yielding nothing, primarily because I didn't know a concise way to pose a question.

The 'title' bar of this table has its first title as an Expression.  This expression simply displays the name of a month or the words 'Year To Date' based on the field value it receives from my stored proc.

Months January to May display in order, THEN it displays Year To Date, followed by the remaining months in their proper order. Not sure why it is doing it or where to look for problems.
[image]

The tables should display all the months in order followed by the Year To Date table. Below is the expression used for the textbox:

[image]

The report is much to large to display a screenshot of it.

Where would I look for a setting that determines the order for displaying the generated tables?

Comment: There is not enough information to go on, it's not even clear what you think is wrong. If possible, edit your question to show what the report was like before, what you have changed and what "weird" behaviour you now see.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I edited the question

Comment: You'll need to see what group your textbox is in (row group or column group) and check the sorting properties of that group. It might help when debugging to replace the expression with just the PostMonthNumber field, at least you can see if it's the order of the data that is definitely wrong.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thanks, the report had a number of groupings and I located the one for the table and it had no sorting on the row group.  Adding sorting to it fixed my problem.